# List workflow to create an associated Document Library Document

Tags: sharepoint-2013, workflow

Sharepoint 2013 - on premises using 2010 workflows
I created a sharepoint list with simple fields (title, info - plain text field)
I created a document library  -which defaults to a document template for new files.
When I create a new document, using the template (which uses docment properties to populate areas) it works fine.
I need to create a workflow on the list which will create a new document in the library, populating it with fields from the list.
So I created a list workflow, triggered for new items, which does a create item in the library.
It fills in the values for all required fields.  I used "xxx-modified date" as the path.  (I tried previously using the document library path but didn't work).
The workflow fails on creating the item with the message "The workflow count not create list item.  Be sure the list exists and the user has permissions..."
I'm an SCA so I have permissions. The word "list" in the workflow message is talking about the document library I believe, as libraries are really a special form of lists.
I also tried making this workflow a reusable workflow, pointing at the site content type (which is the only CT used in the library) but I get the same message.
So after 4 hours, I'm stumped.  I've been using workflows since 2010 but no joy here.
Any advice welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to  create the workflow with elevated permissions, maybe it would work for you.

Please refer to this article for more:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/create-a-workflow-with-elevated-permissions-by-using-the-sharepoint-workflo

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I already have SCA  but I can put in an impersonization step for users to not run into problems - though I doubt this is a permissions problem.